# 'initializer_list' file not found

Tags: c++, c++11, debian

Context:

```
you@laptop:~$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
```

Whenever I try to `make` a script which needs `c++11` support, I get the following output:

> fatal error: 'initializer_list' file not found

I have tried adding `-stdlib=libc++` and `-std=c++11` to `CXXFLAGS` with no success.

How do I fix the `'initializer_list'` error?

I double-checked doing `find /usr/include -name initializer_list` and this returned:

> /usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list
>   /usr/include/c++/5/initializer_list

---

EDIT: here is the [Makefile](https://github.com/sandstorm-io/sample-static-publishing-app/blob/master/sandstorm-integration/Makefile).

Comment: Could you simply have omitted the `std` prefix and wrtten `intializer_list` when `std::intializer_list` was called for?

Comment: The error is regarding a file, not a type. So presumably the code contains an `#include <initializer_list>` instruction and the compiler can't find the `initializer_list` file.

Comment: That's right @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0):

You can run a following command to see the search path for include files:

```
# clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

For the Docker image I was using the output is the following:

```
clang version 3.5.1 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
 "/opt/llvm/bin/clang-3.5" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /opt/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.1 -internal-isystem /opt/llvm/bin/../include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /opt/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /opt/llvm/include/c++/v1 -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/ -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir / -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 3.5.1 based upon LLVM 3.5.1svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/llvm/bin/../include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.1/include
 /opt/llvm/include/c++/v1
 /usr/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 318 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2
```

The compiler complains that it cannot find the `initializer_list` in the list of paths for <...> search.
I was able to find it in this directory:

```
# find /opt/llvm/include/c++/v1 -name initializer_list
/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/initializer_list
```

I would suggest checking if your LLVM installation is correct with regards to the default search path settings shown above.

Comment: ok, when I run:

`# clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null`

I get:

`#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/include/clang/3.5.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include`

So it's clear to me that I need to add the `/usr/include/c++/4.9/` dir but how? I have tried adding `-I/usr/include/c++/5/` but it results on another library missing:

 `/usr/include/c++/5/initializer_list:41:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found`

Comment: It seems that CLang finds a GCC 6 installation but the package `libstdc++-6-dev` is absent.