# compile simple github fails at ext submodule

Tags: c++, github, meson-build

i am trying to compile this git https://github.com/yapb/yapb locally

i am using ubuntu 64bit, and it says i must compile 32bit

i am using now

```
CC=clang CXX=clang meson build-clang
```

but get this error

````
FAILED: yapb.so.p/src_chatlib.cpp.o
clang -Iyapb.so.p -I. -I.. -fvisibility=hidden -flto
-fcolor-diagnostics -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall
-Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c++14
-fno-exceptions -O3 -DVERSION_GENERATED -fno-threadsafe-statics
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -m32 -pedantic -fdata-sections
-ffunction-sections -mtune=generic -fno-builtin -funroll-loops
-fomit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fvisibility=hidden
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fPIC
-isystem../ext/crlib -isystem../ext -isystem../inc -isystem..
-isystem. -MD -MQ yapb.so.p/src_chatlib.cpp.o -MF
yapb.so.p/src_chatlib.cpp.o.d -o yapb.so.p/src_chatlib.cpp.o -c
../src/chatlib.cpp
In file included from ../src/chatlib.cpp:8:
In file included from ../inc/yapb.h:10:
In file included from ../ext/hlsdk/extdll.h:28:
In file included from ../ext/crlib/crlib/string.h:17:
../ext/crlib/crlib/array.h:15:10: fatal error: 'initializer_list' file not found
#include <initializer_list>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the pre-requisites mentioned in [YaPB Building the Bot](https://yapb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html) page.

Try and open a regular CMD (instead of Powershell), making sure it inherits all your previous setups (meaning its `%PATH%` does reference `g++.exe`, `pip.exe`, and so on.

Comment: im now on ubuntu 64bit, and managed to compile it with gcc and clang, however it seems i need to compile it in 32 bit using meson. i dont know how to do that

Comment: @aaaa You are using WSL2?

Comment: im using virtualbox with ubuntu 64bit

Comment: im now compiling with clang, but get an error, see post

Comment: @aaaa OK. Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410918/6309) can help.

Comment: gives me a new error